# How to estimate gas cost to update uint256?

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, gas, ethers.js

I have a need to update a uint256 state variable in a solidity contract that was deployed with a proxy. When calling the function to update the variable programmatically with Ethers, the total cost is 0.0001279 ETH, ~$.24 at today's value, as you can see below.

[image]

The update function is:

```
uint256 public price;
...
function setTokenPrice(uint tokenPrice) public onlyOwner{ price = tokenPrice; }
```

The transaction on the Sepolia testnet and can be seen here: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xf6a817bb819e1c04f528ee63ac17d0c3e5445bfd9da66bfd2dbcb30ef8b2c389

Why did the total cost end up being much higher than the estimated price I saw in Remix (21000 wei)? I know gas fluctuates depending on demand, but I would like to be sure that is the cause and not something I control in the contract/logic. Could this price be because the contract was deployed with a proxy? Any guidance is much appreciated. Thank you!